# How to obtain the p-values ​of a gamlssMX model?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, gaussian-mixture-distribution, gamlss

I am working with a dataset that includes a binary target variable (0 or 1).
I have built a model with the gamlssMX() function included on the "gamlss.mx" package to explain a continuous target variable as a function of continuous
and qualitative features, alongside with the target one. My goal is to find out if this pathway is significant, but when I build the gamlssMX() model,
I get an error when applying the summary() function, which returns p-values associated with each of the features in other models, such as the linear model.

If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Does your target variable take values Y>=0 ?
If so, you could fit a zero-adjusted continuous distribution,
for example
ZAGA,  zero-adjusted gamma distribution
ZAIG,  zero-adjusted inverse Gaussian distribution.

The gamlss.inf package in R (for gamlss.inflated) also
allows any gamlss continuous distribution for Y>0
to be adjusted to have a point probability at zero.

See Chapter 9 (p177-187) of the book
Rigby et al.(2019) ‘Distributions for Modeling Location, Scale, and Shape: Using GAMLSS in R’.

Alternatively you could fit a binary model for Y=0 or not 0,
and a continuous distribution for Y>0.

To test the significance of an explanatory variable, it is better (more reliable) to use a generalised likelihood ratio  test:

[i.e. compare the difference in global deviance when removing the explanatory variable from the model,
against a Chi-squared distribution with the difference in degrees of freedom,
(rather than using Wald tests from the summary() output,
which are less reliable)].